# Combine rows based on column names pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks something like this

```
NAME              FORMULA.   CHARGE MNX_ID       CHEBI_ID   HMDB_ID
156 (+)-alpha-pinene    C10H16  0   NaN           <NA>    HMDB0652  
155 (+)-alpha-pinene    C10H16  0   NaN           36740     Nan
154 (+)-alpha-pinene    C10H16  0   MNXM163755    NaN      Nan
```

and I would like to group the rows by NAME FORMULA and CHARGE and combine the latter columns so I get.

```
>   NAME              FORMULA.   CHARGE MNX_ID       CHEBI_ID   HMDB_ID
>   (+)-alpha-pinene    C10H16  0   MNXM163755    36740   HMDB0652
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

use `stack/unstack`:

```
# df = df.replace('Nan', np.NAN)
df = df.set_index(['NAME', 'FORMULA.', 'CHARGE']).stack().unstack().reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
               NAME FORMULA.  CHARGE      MNX_ID CHEBI_ID   HMDB_ID
0  (+)-alpha-pinene   C10H16       0  MNXM163755  36740.0  HMDB0652
```